# Solving a non-homogeneous recurrence relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$a_n = a_{n-1} + (n+3)(n+2)(n+1)$

for $n > 0$ and $a_0 = 6$

I know how to solve the first homogeneous part. But I am having troubles making sense of the non-homogeneous part.

Answer (score 1):

By telescopic sum we obtain:
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a_{k-1})+a_0=6+\sum_{k=1}^n(k^3+6k^2+11k+6)=$$
$$=6+\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}+6\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+11\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+6n=$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{4}.$$
There is also the following nice way:
$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^n((k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)-k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3))=$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use brute force. Since you have a cubic term, you can assume that the result will be a quartic polynomial.

Let $$a_n=b_0+b_1 n + b_2n^2+b_3 n^3+b_4 n^4$$ Replace and group terms to get
$$(b_1-b_2+b_3-b_4-6)+(2 b_2-3 b_3+4 b_4-11) n+(3 b_3-6 b_4-6) n^2+(4
   b_4-1) n^3=0$$ Since this must hold  for all $n$, just set all coefficients equal to $0$ which sucessively gives $b_4=\frac 14$, $b_3= \frac 52$ , $b_2= \frac {35}4$ , $b_1=\frac {25}2$ giving
$$a_n=\frac{1}{4} n (n+5) (n^2+5n+10)+b_0$$ and $b_0=a_0$; for your specific case $(a_0=6), this leads to Michael Rozenberg's result.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution via the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity):
$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (k+3)(k+2)(k+1) = 6\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k+3}{3} = 6 \binom{n+4}{4} = \frac{(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}{4}$$